# Dynamic inject of code into iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

i'm tring to build my own ads netowork, but i am stuck in days at the same point, how can i dynamical inject content (Like images or gif), into an iframe, and keeping everytime the same src attribute (`<iframe src="http://example.com/iframe.js" </iframe>`) attribute? I tried everything with php but nothing work.

Comment: This is the **fourth** time within not even a full day that you are asking that question, after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46026806/how-to-have-a-constant-iframe-with-a-dynamic-content, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032299/how-to-get-a-dynamic-content-on-iframe, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035056/how-to-get-a-dynamic-content-on-iframe-for-example-in-ads You should really go learn some basics before asking here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a dynamic content on <iframe>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46032299/how-to-get-a-dynamic-content-on-iframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add content into an iframe, you can do something like:

```
var doc = document.getElementById('yourIframe').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write('Some test content');
doc.close();
```

Comment: could i do this : doc.write ('http://example.com/example.gif')? Or is there another way to inject a gif,image ecc...?

Comment: Well you'd write out an `img` tag of course.... `doc.write('<img src="/path/to/image.gif" />');`